# PHAsset not working on iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, ios11, crash-reports, xcode9, phasset

I am facing crash on **PHAsset** on **iOS 11** while fetching photos from some device like iPhone 7 +,

Application crash on **PHImageManager**.

Please check below error log for same,

> Incident Identifier: ECC7F773-6C80-4E89-B892-C998FABF9F46
>   Beta Identifier:     6CA3CB11-2229-4C1D-A30C-D7F898C2A778
>   Hardware Model:      iPhone9,2
>   Process:             MyApp [10398]
>   Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/448A38F9-611C-4A1D-9C0E-936BF1BDB0FD/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Identifier:          com.MyApp
>   Version:             1 (1.0.15)
>   Beta:                YES
>   Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
>   Role:                Foreground
>   Parent Process:      launchd [1]
>   Coalition:           com.MyApp [976]
>   Date/Time:           2017-11-07 14:40:10.9453 -0500
>   Launch Time:         2017-11-07 14:38:40.5255 -0500
>   OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.1 (15B93)
>   Baseband Version:    3.21.01
>   Report Version:      104
>   Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>   Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
>   VM Region Info: 0x8 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4330455032
>         REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
>         UNUSED SPACE AT START
>   --->
>         __TEXT                 00000001021d8000-00000001021dc000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...MyApp]
>   Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
>   Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
>   Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
>   Triggered by Thread:  0
>   Thread 0 name:
>   Thread 0 Crashed:
>   0   ImageIO                         0x000000018507639c hash_table_modify + 404 (x-hash.c:331)
>   1   ImageIO                         0x0000000185076390 hash_table_modify + 392 (x-hash.c:327)
>   2   ImageIO                         0x00000001851d2100 ImageIO_Malloc + 168 (ImageIOMemory.cpp:338)
>   3   ImageIO                         0x00000001851db0c0 HEIFReadPlugin::copyImageBlockSet(InfoRec, CGImageProvider, CGRect, CGSize, __CFDictionary const*) + 780 (imageHEIF.cpp:2121)
>   4   ImageIO                         0x00000001851d9d74 HEIFReadPlugin::CopyImageBlockSetProc(void, CGImageProvider, CGRect, CGSize, __CFDictionary const*) + 132 (imageHEIF.cpp:2666)
>   5   ImageIO                         0x000000018506aa70 IIOImageProviderInfo::copyImageBlockSetWithOptions(CGImageProvider, CGRect, CGSize, __CFDictionary const) + 632 (CGImagePlus.cpp:1900)
>   6   ImageIO                         0x0000000185068340 IIOImageProviderInfo::CopyImageBlockSetWithOptions(void, CGImageProvider, CGRect, CGSize, __CFDictionary const*) + 596 (CGImagePlus.cpp:2198)
>   7   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184a76ac8 img_blocks_create + 276 (CGSImage.c:306)
>   8   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184a7e3c0 img_data_lock + 1840 (CGSImage.c:6531)
>   9   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184a7dc38 CGSImageDataLock + 184 (CGSImage.c:7130)
>   10  CoreGraphics                    0x000000018489e704 ripc_AcquireRIPImageData + 308 (RIPImage.c:134)
>   11  CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184a9287c ripc_DrawImage + 644 (RIPContext.c:1295)
>   12  CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184a82678 CGContextDrawImageWithOptions + 632 (CGContextImage.c:290)
>   13  ImageIO                         0x000000018507157c CGImageCreateCopyWithParametersNew(CGImage, CGColor, CGAffineTransform, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, bool, int, int, bool) + 1588 (CGImageCopy.cpp:682)
>   14  ImageIO                         0x00000001850438e4 IIOImageSource::createThumbnailAtIndex(unsigned long, IIODictionary*) + 1812 (CGImageSource.cpp:1557)
>   15  ImageIO                         0x0000000185046de0 CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex + 364 (CGImageSource.cpp:3447)
>   16  PhotoLibraryServices            0x00000001909d45c4 _PLCreateCGImageFromDataUsingImageIOWithFormat + 788 (UIImageAdditions.m:355)
>   17  PhotoLibraryServices            0x00000001909d4d10 PLCreateImageFromDataWithFormat + 1736 (UIImageAdditions.m:469)
>   18  PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190a9edbc _172+[PLImageLoadingUtilities assetsdImageForAsset:withFormat:allowPlaceholder:optimalSourcePixelSize:networkAccessAllowed:trackCPLDownload:sync:isCanceledHandler:completion:]_block_invoke.44 + 384 (PLImageLoadingUtilities.m:111)
>   19  PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190a9e9a0 +[PLImageLoadingUtilities _assetsdImageForAsset:withFormat:allowPlaceholder:optimalSourcePixelSize:networkAccessAllowed:trackCPLDownload:sync:isCanceledHandler:completion:] + 600 (PLImageLoadingUtilities.m:142)
>   20  Photos                          0x000000019178d698 -[PHCoreImageManager _fetchAnySizeImageAsNon5551BytesPossiblyThruAssetsdAndCPLWithRequest:library:format:optimalSourcePixelSize:wantsProperties:networkAccessAllowed:networkAccessForced:trackCPLDownload:sync:completionHandler:] + 1208 (PHImageManager.m:1072)
>   21  Photos                          0x000000019178f9e8 _163-[PHCoreImageManager fetchAnySizeImageAsNon5551BytesWithRequest:library:format:bestFormat:optimalSourcePixelSize:sync:fireAndForgetCPLDownload:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 268 (PHImageManager.m:1136)
>   22  Photos                          0x000000019178e808 -[PHCoreImageManager _fetchAnySizeImageAsNon5551BytesWithRequest:library:format:bestFormat:optimalSourcePixelSize:sync:fireAndForgetCPLDownload:completionHandler:] + 1080 (PHImageManager.m:1159)
>   23  Photos                          0x00000001917949c8 -[PHCoreImageManager _fetchPreheatableAnySizeImageAsNon5551BytesWithRequest:library:format:bestFormat:preheatItem:optimalSourcePixelSize:sync:fireAndForgetCPLDownload:completionHandler:] + 3692 (PHImageManager.m:1406)
>   24  Photos                          0x000000019179916c -[PHCoreImageManager _handleNormalImageRequest:library:deliveryMode:degradedFormat:bestFormat:optimalSourcePixelSize:wantsImageDataOrURL:sync:isFinalStageOfStagedRequest:isResponseToSharedStreamsDownload:] + 2136 (PHImageManager.m:1826)
>   25  Photos                          0x000000019179758c -[PHCoreImageManager _processImageRequest:sync:] + 2748 (PHImageManager.m:1663)
>   26  Photos                          0x000000019179acac -[PHImageManager requestSynchronousImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:completionHandler:] + 352 (PHImageManager.m:1914)
>   27  Photos                          0x000000019179fd5c -[PHImageManager requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:] + 424 (PHImageManager.m:2312)

Please let me know what could be the reason for crash application.

Comment: i am also facing same issue, do you got solution for same

Comment: i am also facing a production crash with this log, i can't figure out where and what is actually causing this issue, @Jaywant Khedkar did you find root cause or nay solution